# Override the assignment operator in the inheriting class

Tags: c++, oop

```
class A
{
   int Avalue;
   A& operator=(A& copyMe)
   {
       Avalue = copyMe.Avalue;
       return *this;
   }
}

class B:public A
{
   int Bvalue;
   B& operator=(B& copyMe)
   {
       Bvalue = copyMe.Bvalue
       return *this;
   }
}
```

How to invoke the A or the base class assignment operator from the B's assignment operator?.How to handle A's return reference from the assignment operator call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All operators can be thought of as a bit of clever functions, but that's just courtesy of the compiler which is smart enough to infer what are the given operands and pass them into your override. It's a great extensible way of adding nice syntactic sugar in situations where it makes sense, but because of their usual usage, people cannot really see that this is valid, but when you observe your definitions of the overrides, they look like functions and act like functions. So, simply use the scope operator `::` to access the public parts of A's interface.

```
A::operator=(copyMe)
```

Do note you're missing several semicolons and also, classes default to `private` access. To gain access to the copy assignment operator in A, you need to specify it as public:

```
class A
{
  private:
   int Avalue;
  public:
   A& operator=(A& copyMe)
   {
       Avalue = copyMe.Avalue;
       return *this;
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, it is generally good practice to take a const & as argument, for various reasons:

A& operator=(const A & copyMe)

B& operator=(const B & copyMe)

Comment: Indeed, everytime you're passing in something that doesn't change, it really doesn't hurt to make it const. Applies to member methods as well, if it shouldn't change anything, make it const. It saves nerves and time. Also, I'd recommend to get into it very early on. You start thinking more about what your code should and shouldn't do.

Comment: More importantly, it's almost never a good idea to write a copy assignment operator without also writing a copy constructor. In this case, you'll get away with it because the default copy constructor is fine—but then so is the default assignment operator, so you don't need to define that either. (Also, for this class, I'd pass copyMe by value instead of by reference to the assignment op. It's simpler, and actually easier for the compiler to optimize—not that it matters much for a pair of ints.)

Answer (score 1):

Call the assignment operator (or any other function) explicitly using the scope operator:
 A::operator=( someval );

Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `A::operator=(copyMe)` in the derived op. Also, copies should be of *non-const* reference.